# What older flags/ where does the * point to?

Tags: support, flag-history

In my flag history (<sup>https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/{userid}</sup>), I see:

> <sub><sup>*</sup> older flags were not recorded helpful/declined</sub>

What is this? Where does the asterisk point to?

Should this only be shown if there are old flags?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, that note is valid for all the flag categories:

- The sum of 758, 17, and 77 is not 855 (moderation attention flags)
- The sum of 43 and 2 is not 47 (posts marked spam)
- 10 is different from 9 (posts marked offensive)
- The sum of 26 and 11 is not 40 (comments flagged)

That means there are flags for which the system doesn't know if they were deemed helpful or declined. The reason is that in the past that information was not recorded. That is what the note says.