# What are the changes done in flagging questions?

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

I am getting this in my flag summary. Can somebody please explain what they signify?

Also, **active flag** changed to **pending flag**.

> ```
> 299    moderator attention flags
> 22     waiting for review
> 204    deemed helpful
> 4      declined
> 18     disputed
>
> 3      posts marked spam
> 2      deemed helpful
> 1      declined
> 1      post marked offensive
> 1      declined
> 9      comments flagged
> ```

---

> - older flags were not recorded helpful/declined

What does it mean?

At least *it should be better to add a reason behind **declined flags***.

Comment: See this Meta Stack Overflow post - [Why were my older close flags “aged away”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. *moderator attention flags* - total number of flags you have cast.
2. *waiting for review* - amount of flags that are still active/not handled, i.e. waiting for review by moderators. (they might also get disputed)
3. *deemed helpful* - total amout of flags that were marked as "helpful" by the moderator handling them.
4. *declined* - total amount of flags that were declined by the moderator handling them. Many times the moderator adds a reason, which is visible to the left (not in the summary), near each declined flag item.
5. *disputed* - explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag).

---

1. *posts marked spam* - total amount of spam flags you have cast.
2. *deemed helpful* - total amount of spam flags that were marked helpful, either by reaching 6 flags on the post or a moderator casting binding flag/deleting the post manually.
3. *declined* - amount of spam flags that a moderator manually declined.

---

*comments flagged* - total amount of comment flags you have cast.

---

*older flags were not recorded helpful/declined* - explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183755/what-older-flags-where-does-the-point-to).

Comment: *man! ...thanks a lot*